# postfix maildir with custom path

Tags: postfix, maildir

I need to have postfix store mail in a maildir in /var/mail/<DOMAIN>/<USER>.  I've got

```
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
```

and I'm preparing

```
home_mailbox =
```

but I don't know where to go from there.

Assistance please?

**EDIT**: SF ate my tag.  Please re-read to determine paths.

Comment: Should I assume the < DOMAIN > will be variable (not a hard coded)?

Comment: Correct.  Otherwise, this would be easy :)

Comment: All right. Deleting my answer, as it isn't precisely what you are asking.

Comment: Are you using Procmail as the delivery agent?

Comment: Not yet.  Haven't gotten that far :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want Vritual mailbox delivery.  [This is well-documented at the Postfix website, and will do *exactly* what you are asking](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox).  Note that you will need to do some lookup tables for this, although the official docs do mention that you can use a SQL backend at some point, should it all become too unmanageable.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of to accomplish what you want is the using Procmail (or alike with similar capabilities) as the delivery agent. With procmail, something like this on the system wide procmailrc would work:

```
:0
* RECIPIENT ?? .*@\/.*$
{ DOMAIN = "$MATCH" }
MAILDIR="/var/mail/$DOMAIN/$USER"
DEFAULT="$MAILDIR/"
```

Comment: As there are other MTAs that may use Procmail in a similar fashion, +1 for MTA-agnostic answer... :)